# The probability of a successful optical alignment in an assembly of an optical data storage product is 0.9.

Tags: probability, statistics

Can someone tell me if I did part a,b,c correctly and help me with part d? Thank you for the help.

(a) What is the probability that the ﬁrst successful alignment requires exactly four trials?

P(x=4) = .9 * (.1)^3 = .0009

(b) What is the probability that the ﬁrst successful alignment requires at most four trials?

P(x <= 4) so it would be P(x=1)+ P(x=2)+P(x=3)+P(x=4) = .9999

(c) What is the probability that the ﬁrst successful alignment requires at least four trials?

P(x>4) so it would be 1-p(x<=4) = .001

(d)What is the average number of trials necessary to obtain the ﬁrst successful alignment? I'm lost on this one.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(d)$ Geometric distribution.

If the probability of success on each trial is $p$, then the probability that the $k$th trial is the first success is

$P(X=k) = (1-p)^{k-1}p$

The expected value of a geometric random variable is

$E[X] = \frac{1}{p}$

Comment: oh, so it will just be (.9/(1-.9)) = 9?

Comment: @Ayechan_San No, it was incorrect. Now there is the correct equation.

Comment: @Ayechan_San Yes, i wrote a wrong expectaion first.

Answer (score 0):

Answers (a) and (b) are okay.

For (c) "at least 4" is $\{X \geq 4\}$, although you managed to arrive at the right answer, so I suspect you have a typo. $$\mathsf P\{X\geq 4\} = 0.1^3$$

As to (d), have you not recognised that $X$ has a *geometric distribution*?   What is the formula for the expected value of a geometric distributed random variable?